# Javascript shortest possible check for undefined, if it is assign a default value

Tags: javascript

If passing params or an object full of properties into function, it's useful to check for undefined params and give default values to those that are undefined.

Without using a library function like jQuery extent, what would be the shortest about of code to do this kind of assigning defaults?

Here is the shortest I can think of:

```
var test;
var output = (typeof test != "undefined") ? test : "Default";
```

Before someone suggests:

```
var test;
var output = test || "Default";
```

That will not work with false, 0 or ""

Comment: `undefined` is a keyword so you shouldn't need to place it in quotes.

Comment: @War10ck `typeof` operator always returns a string, that's why quotes are needed.

Comment: @Teemu Did not know that. Guess I need to look into that more. Learn something new everyday. My apologies for that. Thanks for the correction. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var output = test != null ? test : "Default";
```

I.g:

```
null == undefined // true
null == null // true
null == 0 // false
null == "" //false
null == false // false
```

Comment: ```null === undefined
=> false```
& 
```null == undefined
=> true```

My static analyser won't let me use ```==```

Answer (score 4):

In ES2021 this is now possible using the [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

Usage:

```js
const str = null ?? 'default string';
console.log(str);
// expected output: "default string"

const num = 0 ?? 42;
console.log(num);
// expected output: 0

const bool = false ?? true;
console.log(bool)
// expected output: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if the *"undefined"* it the longest value of types, the shortest way to check object presence is

```
!(typeof console).charAt(8)
```

where *"console"* is our examinated object.
*.charAt(8)* will return empty string "" if object is anything else than *"undefined"*, that equals *false*
It's a safe way for old IE supporting. But if u need only modern browsers support, you can use just

```
if(!(typeof console)[8]) { doWork(); }
```

to check that object is defined.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jed/140bytes/wiki/Byte-saving-techniques is your friend:

```
var output = test===[]._ ? "Default" : test;
```

Shorter:

```
var output=test===[]._?"Default":test;
```

No spaces needed between operators and tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var output = if(test === undefined) ? test: "Default";
```

If you know that you will never pass `0`, `false`, or `""` as valid parameters you could simplify this to be:

```
var output = if(test) ? test : "Default";
```

However, this gets into the cryptic "truthy falsey" part of JavaScript. By having the `===` you are doing an equality check with type comparison.

Hope this helps.